# What can I do to solve the moisture problem in my bathroom?

Tags: walls, moisture

My bathroom walls are done in concrete not drywall. I installed a ceiling fan. After showering, the walls are covered with moisture.

What can I do to eliminate the moisture?

Comment: A ceiling fan, or an exhaust fan?

Comment: Did this moisture problem begin occurring after you installed the fan?

Comment: Are you sure the walls are concrete and not plaster or some other coating? Are they exterior walls? Are they insulated?

Answer (score 8):

Condensation happens whenever hot air meets cold surfaces, and the air after a shower is hot and very humid.

You'll always get some condensation, but there are a few things done to mitigate this:

- Normal interior walls and well-insulated exterior walls are usually not a lot colder than the air temperature. (The colder the walls are, the more condensation will happen.)
- An exhaust fan will remove some of the humid, hot air (and since hot air rises, the exhaust fan is on or near the ceiling which has the greatest effect), and regular (room temperature, and regular humidity) air will be drawn in from HVAC vents or under the bottom of the door. Opening the door will help even more.
- A semi-gloss or high-gloss paint is used (usually these are labelled Kitchen and Bath) which holds up better to high humidity, condensation and regular cleaning.

If your walls are actually solid concrete or concrete blocks, then they definitely are going to be colder as concrete is a poor insulator. This is why in the same room concrete will feel cooler to the touch than drywall, which will feel cooler to the touch than a towel.

Answer (score 1):

Are they solid concrete? Is it colder outside than in? If so, not much you can do. Steam will condense on cold surfaces. The exhaust fan can certainly help, though.

Answer (score 0):

You could try leaving the bathroom door open while showering or opening it afterward when you are done. Opening the window will also help a bit (if it's cold open it only a crack and close it when you're done).

Comment: Leaving the door open while showering might help with the moisture problem in the bathroom, but it could cause a moisture problems in the rest of the house.